# sh- 3.2# instead of #?

Tags: shell, ubuntu, root

i am trying to invoke a root shell via buffer overflow. 
I get sh- 3.2$ instead of #.  It seems like sh- 3.2$ is similar to # as it also issues commands.  However it seems to be permanently stuck.  The exit command does not work.  What does sh- 3.2$ mean?

Comment: This is the default PS1 variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either `#` or `sh-3.2#` is your shell prompt, stored in the `$PS1` variable.  The default prompt is going to depend on how your system and account are configured.  `$PS1` is typically set in any of `/etc/profile`, `$HOME/.profile`, `$HOME/.bashrc`, `$HOME/.bash_profile`, etc.

`#` normally indicates a root shell; `$` normally indicates a non-root shell.  `3.2` is the shell version.  So `sh-3.2$` is telling you that you *don't* have a root shell. (Typing `whoami` would also tell you that.)

If you're using bash (which you probably are), the syntax of `$PS1` is documented [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Printing-a-Prompt.html) in the Bash manual -- or type `info bash` if you have the Bash documentation installed on your system.